# CSS is wrong in ie while being right in Chrome

Tags: css

I have got this rule for a div:

```css
#dividerTabs {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #FFB4A1;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    bottom: -40px;
}
```

Html:

```
 <div id="dividerTabs"></div>
```

Other rules that apply to the div, when looking at chrome debugger is:

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

The problems is that the div is 2px down, and about 60px to the right, from where it should be in chrome.

Why is this, and how do I correct this?

Comment: you would also need to inspect the position of all of its parents. And if the error is in IE, it might be more instructive to check which rules are appied according to IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Normalize CSS](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) it will help rendering HTML pages properly in all major browsers

OR

[HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) the default template. This is solid!

Answer (score 3):

Browsers render CSS differently or might have different default values for CSS properties. Try using a CSS Reset in your web page.

Try this one:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

or this one:
http://www.cssreset.com/

Make sure you use the CSS Reset first before any of your CSS.

Comment: I know about the reset.. but i am not going to apply it

Answer (score 2):

There might be an issue with the `border-radius` and `height`. Your `height` is `5px`, and your `border-radius` is `15px`. This will cause the border to invert, which may be leading to the offset.

Comment: didnt know that both relate... the offset and the border radius

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd I haven't actually tested it, but I know when I design things with a border-radius more than half of the height, then the border-radius actually starts pushing outwards in a weird pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the parent `div`s. Check the CSS. The `border-radius` may also be causing you problems, I've had something similar happen to me before in IE.